# js function calling another js function and returning a value problem

Tags: javascript, json

i have this JS function:

```
function ax_get_new_msg_cnt()
{   var mTimer; 
    var last_msg_id;
    mTimer = setTimeout('ax_get_new_msg_cnt();',30000);
    $.getJSON('/apps_dev.php/profile/newMessageCheck', function(data) 
{
        $('#newMessageDiv').text("You have " + data.msg_cnt + " new ");
        last_msg_id = data.msg_id;
    });
    return last_msg_id;
}
```

then i have the js function where i call `ax_get_new_msg_cnt()`:

```
function ax_get_new_msg_details()
{
var mTimer; 
mTimer = setTimeout('ax_get_new_msg_details();',30000);
$.getJSON('/apps_dev.php/messagebox/newMessageDetails', function(data) 
{
    var str='<tr>';
    str += "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left' id='td_date'>"+data.td_date+'</td>';
    str += "<td align='left' id='td_subject'><a href='#' style='color:#ff0000 !important' class='spn_small_red_rbc'>"+data.td_subject+"</a></td>";
    str += "<td class='td_show_contact_item' align='left' id='td_from'>"+data.td_from +"</td>";
    //str += "<td id='block_url'>"+data.block_url+"</td>";
    str +='<tr>';
    var tbl = $('#td_date').parents('table');
    var msg_id = ax_get_new_msg_cnt();
    console.log(msg_id);
    if (msg_id == data.td_id)
    {

    }
    else
    {
       $(tbl).append(str);

    }   
});
}
```

in the above function i get `msg_id` as undefined...
can i do it the way i have it or is there another way please?
only if `msg_id != data.td_id` i want to do the append
thank you

Comment: Eval is Evil! Using a string as the first argument in a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` call creates an implicit (and unnecessary) call to `eval`. Instead of `setTimeout('ax_get_new_msg_cnt();', 30000);` just pass the function name: `setTimeout(ax_get_new_msg_cnt, 30000);`.  Less code and less computational time used as well.  The same thing applies to the `setTimeout` call in `ax_get_new_msg_details`.

Comment: oops did not even see that! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the asynchronous way of programming.

In your first method, when it gets called it starts an async JSON request to the webserver, which will return later in time, but your `$.getJSON` call return immediately, so your `last_msg_id` variable will be untouched and this untouched (`undefined`) variable will be returned by `ax_get_new_msg_cnt` function.

Later when the webserver returned with the answer and the answer is read by your browser it passes back to your callback function which sets the `last_msg_id`.

You can write `console.log` debug messages to see the timings:

1. if you insert a `console.log('JSON start');` to your `ax_get_new_msg_details` method before the `$.getJSON` call
2. then one `console.log('Response arrived');` to inside the `function(data)` part
3. and an another one right before the end with `console.log('JSON request sent');`

then, you'll probably see the way of executing.

Answer (score 0):

What ever you want to do with msg_id you need to do it in $.getJSON callback function. You can not return it. The Ajax call is asyncron, so you have to wait till it is finished to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Because the [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method is asynchronous, your `ax_get_new_msg_cnt()` function will return before the data is received, leaving `last_msg_id` as `undefined`.

Moreover, I think that the URL parameter for `$.getJSON()` should point to a file, not to a folder.

Note: you could improve your code by using the [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) method to set a default timeout for all your jQuery ajax requests.